# How to call a directive's function from the controller on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that controls a personalized multiselect. Sometimes from the main controller I'd like to clear all multiselects. I have the multiselect value filling a "`filter`" bidirectional variable, and I am able to remove content from there, but when doing that I also have to change some styles and other content. In other words: I have to call a method belonging to the directive from a button belonging to the controller. Is that even posible with this data structure?:

(By the way, I found other questions and examples but their directives didn't have their own scope.)

```
function MultiselectDirective($http, $sce) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'temp.html',
        scope: {
            filter: "=",
            name: "@",
            url: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
           //do stuff
           scope.function_i_need_to_call = function(){
              //updates directtive template styles
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: define as $parent scope function , example: scope.$parent.function_i_need_to_call = function(){..}) inside directive, and then call same method in controller with $scope.function_i_need_to_call()

Comment: You can `scope.$watch` `filter` and then call the function according to the current value.

Comment: @saikumar but what if the directive is working in multiple elements?

Comment: then do one thing. scope.$on('function_i_need_to_call', function(){   }) inside directive, then $broadcast where ever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution and the angular way - use `event`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/c4ecntrf/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleOneController', function($scope) {
   $scope.raise = function(val){
     $scope.$broadcast('raise.event',val);
   };
  })
  .controller('ExampleTwoController', function($scope) {
   $scope.raise = function(val){
     $scope.$broadcast('raise.event',val);
   };
  })
  .directive('simple', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.$on('raise.event',function(event,val){
     console.log('i`m from '+val);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h3>
      ExampleOneController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
      <button ng-click="raise(1)" simple>
       Raise 1
      </button>
      
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h3>
      ExampleTwoController
    </h3>
    <form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
       <button ng-click="raise(2)" simple>
       Raise 2
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think better solution to link from controller to directives is this one:

```
// in directive

   return {
      scope: {
                controller: "=",         
             },
      controller: function($scope){
         $scope.mode = $scope.controller.mode;
         $scope.controller.function_i_need_to_call = function(){}
         $scope.controller.currentState = state;
      }
   }

// in controller
function testCtrl($scope){

     // config directive
     $scope.multiselectDirectiveController = {
           mode: 'test',
     };

     // call directive methods
     $scope.multiselectDirectiveController.function_i_need_to_call();

     // get directive property
     $scope.multiselectDirectiveController.currentState;
}

// in template
<Multiselect-directive controller="multiselectDirectiveController"></Multiselect-directive>
```

Comment: if there is more than one instance of the directive, those methods will override, I'm afraid

Comment: for multiple instance of one directive in this way you pass different $scope.multiselectDirectiveController variable to directive and NO Override happens, for Example: $scope.userMultiselectController, $scope.vehicleMultiselectController

Comment: The best solution and the angular way - use event. The answer below is the simplest solution not the best solution, if you want to call many methods of one directive for example a map directive, then you have many performance issue. so broadcast is not the solution, It is the simplest solution